# How to compare two lines in a file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

Let say I have a file `foo.csv`:

```
timestamp,id,ip_src,ip_dst,protocol,msg    
08/20-12:01:22.172612 ,1000001,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.1,ICMP,"ICMP test detected"
08/20-12:03:22.172809 ,1000001,10.0.0.6,10.0.0.3,ICMP,"ICMP test detected"
08/20-12:06:22.172940 ,1000001,10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,ICMP,"ICMP test detected"
08/20-12:06:22.172838 ,1000001,10.0.0.9,10.0.0.2,ICMP,"ICMP test detected"
08/20-12:10:23.173945 ,1000001,10.0.0.8,10.0.0.1,ICMP,"ICMP test detected"
08/20-12:19:23.173982 ,1000001,10.0.0.1,10.0.0.8,ICMP,"ICMP test detected"
```

I want to how to compare `ip_src` from the last line and check the line above it until find a line that have same ip address.

Can I do that?

This is my code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile="/var/log/foo.csv"

tail -s 0 -n 1 -f $logfile | while read line; do
    time=`echo $line | cut -f 1 -d ","`
    id=`echo $line | cut -f 2 -d ","`
    src=`echo $line | cut -f 3 -d ","`
    dst=`echo $line | cut -f 4 -d ","`
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd flip the file around using `tac` - then you can note the *first* value of the third comma-separated field, and print when you see it again:

```
$ tac "$logfile" | awk -F, 'NR==1 {seen[$3]++; next} seen[$3] {print; quit}'
08/20-12:06:22.172940 ,1000001,10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,ICMP,"ICMP test detected"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another with awk:

```
awk -F, '{a[ip] = nr; nr = NR; ip = $3} END {print a[$3]}' foo.csv
```

This saves the previous line's IP and line number to the array `a`. After all lines have been processed, the last line number hasn't been updated yet - it's slot is still occupied by the line number of the last occurrence of that IP.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, something like this would do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

last_ip_address="$(tail -1 "$1"  | cut -d, -f3)"
echo Last IP address: "$last_ip_address"
last_line="$(cut -d, -f3 "$1"  | grep -n "$last_ip_address" | cut -d: -f1 | tail -2 | head -n 1)"
echo Last line that has it: "$last_line"
```

Usage:

```
$./script.sh <FILE>
```

In your example:

```
$ ./script.sh foo.csv
Last IP address: 10.0.0.1
Last line that has it: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

try one more solution with only awk.

```
awk '
{
  a[FNR]=$0
}
END{
split(a[FNR], array,",");
for(i=FNR;i>1;i--){
  split(a[i-1], array1,",");
  if(array[3] == array1[3]){
    print a[i-1];
}
}
}
' Input_file
```

This will look for all lines above which have same 3rd field as last line of Input_file, so if you want only very 1st match of that 3rd field of last line then add either exit or quit after print a[i-1], let me know if this helps you.